# The comments should not be deleted

Tags: discussion

Every time that someone don't like a someone else comment , they are deleted.
This should not going to happen in a free and open forum.
Of course , if comments contains insults , denigration , racism , bad words... should be deleted.
But if someone has not what to say at a specific point , deletion is not the solution.
And sometimes the situation became ridiculous :
Some comments are deleted , and the remaining comments have no sense without the deleted comments.

Comment: The original poster of the comment can delete it at any time, I do this all the time when the comment is no longer useful, more users should clean up their comments like I do.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are designed to be temporary clarifications about specific questions/answers and as such are cleared at regular intervals.

As the [Comments privilege page mentions](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment)

> - Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.